# Trouble accessing Heroku's config vars with os.environ in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm hosting a Django app on Heroku and I do not want my database credentials in the settings.py file to be visible in GitHub. Rather, I want them to be accessed in Heroku's config vars.   Heroku's docs says it's possible to access the config vars in Python code like this:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
s3 = S3Connection(os.environ['S3_KEY'], os.environ['S3_SECRET'])
```

So I set the relevant config vars like this:

```
heroku config:set PASSWORD=madeuppassword
```

And I tried to access the config vars in the source code like is says like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ['ENGINE'],
        'NAME': os.environ['NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['USER'],
        'PORT': os.environ['PORT'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['HOST']
    }
}
```

However when running the server I get this error in my command prompt:

```
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ENGINE'
```

To the best of my knowledge I set and accessed Heroku's config vars as it's demonstrated in their docs but I keep getting this error.  What am I possibly doing wrong that it keeps bringing up this error?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't do this at all, but use either the django-heroku package, which does this for you automatically, or the dj-database-url one, which requires a line of configuration. (But note that your error message does not match your code.)

Comment: The error msg has capitalized (`Engine`), but your code shows uppercase str (`ENGINE`). Could there be a mistake with that?

Comment: Or add your complete error stacktrace, so that we can figure out which line of code raises the error.